# Error in maximization optimization problem in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am solving a optimization problem in MATLAB. It is a maximization problem. Following is the code:

```
x = optimvar("x", "LowerBound",0);
y = optimvar("y", "LowerBound",0);
z = optimvar('z');
prob = optimproblem;
prob.Objective =(2.583*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y );
prob.Constraints.cons1 = (4.616*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y ) <= 1;
prob.Constraints.cons2 = (4.616*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y )>=0;
prob.Constraints.cons3 = (8.303*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y ) <= 1;
prob.Constraints.cons4 = (8.303*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y )>=0;
prob.Constraints.cons5 = (2.583*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y ) <= 1;
prob.Constraints.cons6 = (2.583*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y ) >= 0;
prob.Constraints.cons7 = (16.169*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y ) <= 1;
prob.Constraints.cons8 = (16.169*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y ) >= 0;
prob.Constraints.cons9 = (0.973*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y ) <= 1;
prob.Constraints.cons10 = (0.973*z)/(6.533*x+2.317*y ) >= 0;


sol = solve(prob)
```

However I get the following error:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue

Comment: The optimizer needs an initial guess of the solution vector before it can proceed with finding the actual solution. I'm not familiar with the details of this particular optimizer, but if you look in the MATLAB docs for optimproblem, it should say in there how to go about setting up the initial guess for the optimizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I got the solution to this problem. MATLAB was giving this issue since the objective function and the constraints have a denominator which may be zero. So to get a solution to the problem, remove the denominators and linearize the constraints.